# Keeping one or two days of Yom Tov in towns outside the biblically stipulated borders of Israel?

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz, state-of-israel

If you’re living in [Amman, Jordan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amman), I believe that you need to keep two days of Yom Tov. But if you’re in [Eilat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilat), you keep one day. Why?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5701/what-are-the-halachic-boundaries-of-eretz-yisroel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Amman has never been under Jewish rulership (it was the capital of the Ammonite kingdom). By contrast, Eilat (or neighboring Etzion Gever) was controlled by Shlomo (I Kings 9:26), Yehoshafat (ibid. 22:49), and Uzziah (II Kings 14:22) - it was permanently wrested away only in Achaz's times (ibid. 16:6) - so there is much more reason to consider it part of biblical Israel.

Comment: But wouldn't the important factor be kedusha shenya, or probably even where the messengers reached/could reach?

Comment: Biblical Eilat is not necessarily the same place.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Rambam holds it depends on where messengers actually reached, so even in Israel (and even near Jerusalem) one could keep two days. Others just go by Eretz Yisrael and now by Israel's actual borders.

Comment: @ArielK You lumped two things together there. I know of the Rambam's opinion, which is why I mentioned the messengers. I know of opinions that Kedusha Shniya should matter, which is why I mentioned it. I don't know why the current borders of Israel matter, nor do I know why you lumped that in with Kedusha Shniya.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm saying what many people follow now, it's not hard to see how that developed.

Comment: @ArielK This whole question is about what people should do now. Using the answer as a reason is circular. How did it develop (aside from people not understanding the halacha)?