# Where are the borders of Eretz Israel nowadays?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, geography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the Halachic boundaries of Eretz Yisroel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5701/what-are-the-halachic-boundaries-of-eretz-yisroel)

How far into Jordan/Lebanon/Syria/Egypt is still considered "Halachic" Eretz Israel?